# Simple checksum algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, checksum

Array a of ints contains the digits of a number. For this example I'll insert random numbers but the code must work for any set of numbers. I have to add together the ints in the array and then store the last digit in that sum into a variable called checksum.

In this example, 3 + 5 + 7 = 15 so checksum would = 5. Here's my code so far. How would I go about calculating the checksum?

```
int[] a = { 3, 5, 7 }; 

int checksum = 0;
int i = 0;

while ( i < a.length )
    {
        checksum += a[i];
        i++;
    }

checksum = ???????;
```

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609315/recognizing-when-to-use-the-mod-operator

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the modulus operator. `checksum %= 10`

This basically means, set `checksum` to the remainder of `checksum/10` which happens to be the last digit.

Edit:

Just to offer another suggestion, your `while` loop is really better suited to be a `for-each` loop, just try:

```
for(int i : a){
    checksum += i;
}
```

Read it as "For`int i` in `a`". IMHO this is slightly more understandable and you avoid some typing.

Comment: don`t you mean checksum %= a.length ?

Comment: @ile No, check the example given above, he wants the last digit.

Comment: Sorry, I confused checksum with average value. However, I still think your answer is wrong. If the values were 1, 3, 7 , %= will return 1, whereas it should be 3, if I understood correctly - "store the last number in that sum into a variable called checksum"

Comment: `3 + 5 + 7 = 15 so checksum would = 5` 3+5+7= 15, the last digit of which is 5, or 15%10.

Comment: The question states: "the code must work for any set of numbers."

Comment: Yes, and so does the code above, the last digit of number, n, is always n%10. Can you please explain what your question is?

Comment: Do you mean "digit", not number? I think this is the source of the misunderstanding.

Comment: I'm just going off the question which uses the somewhat confusing term `number` but the example makes it clear that he means `digit`. Im editing to remove the ambuigity

Comment: You are right, I had been thinking of "last but one" number, which was still 5.

Comment: Well, the `for each` is kinda slower than a true for with indexes, so he may want to use a normal for with a large amounts of data.

Comment: Thats true, I just suggested it as an after thought @JavierDiaz