# Confused with % operator

Tags: c#, operators, modulo

I have this simple line of code which shows as remainder `5`:

```
Console.WriteLine(5 % 8);
```

The % operator shows the remainder after first number and second number are divided. So, `5 / 8 = 0,625`. Shouldn't the reminder of the code above be 6 instead of 5? Why do I see 5 when I test in Visual Studio?

Comment: If you divide 5 by 8 you get 0 as quotient and 5 as remainder; that's it.

Comment: You're confused about what "modulo" means, that's all. It doesn't mean "do floating point division, multiply by ten, and truncate".

Comment: shouldn't the remainder be 6? Please explain more what you mean by "confused".

Comment: @BurreIfort Execute this code and look at the results --
 or just google the phrase "integer division remainder" --
 `Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(n => $"{n} % 8 == {n % 8}").ToList()`. You can't make up your own novel definitions for math terms and expect the .NET framework to change to suit you. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: 5 / 8 in **integer** division is ZERO. Five minus zero is five. The result minus the left hand operand (numerator) is the remainder. In floating point division there is no remainder; nothing left over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modulo doesn't give you the first number of the quotient, but the remainder after the second number is divided by the first.

8 doesn't go into 5 at all, so the remainder is the full 5.

See this answer for several other good explanations:

[How does a modulo operation work when the first number is smaller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535656/how-does-a-modulo-operation-work-when-the-first-number-is-smaller)

Comment: it got clear with the explanations in the link. I will accept the answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

How many times does 8 go "cleanly" into 5? Zero times.

```
5 / 8 = 0 (int division)
```

When you do `5 ÷ 8`, how many items are left over? 5.

```
5 % 8 = 5 (modulus division)
```

---

Another way to explain this is:

You have 5 apples. Please distribute those apples among 8 groups, but you must ensure that every group has an equal amount of apples.

You can't do that. You have less apples than the number of groups. You can't give *any* apples to anyone.

And because you didn't give any apples away, you are *left with* 5 apples. That is your remainder.

Comment: With numbers (mathematically) I can, but with apples and pears I can't.

Comment: Remember, you are dealing with integers. You can't have decimal numbers. Yes, on a calculator `5/8=0.625`, but with c# and other programming, it equals 0.

Comment: thanks gunr2171. It is clear now. I thought it should show what comes after zero, but I was wrong. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Everything follows from the fundamental rules of integer division. For integers `x` and `y` suppose we have:

```
q = x / y;
r = x % y;
```

The fundamental rules are:

- `q` and `r` are both integers
- `q * y + r == x`
- Division rounds *towards zero* when inexact

Now that you know the fundamental rules you can work out the values of `5 / 8` and `5 % 8`.

`5 / 8` is an integer.  The exact value is `0.625`, but that's not an integer, so we round *towards zero* and get `0`.  So `q` is `0`.

To compute r we must solve for `q * 8 + r = 5`, which is easy to solve: `r = 5` is the solution.

(Note that there are a few more fundamental rules about dividing by zero, and so on, that you usually don't have to worry about.)